# Strange error C2275 ... illegal use of this type as an expression with member function template and lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11

**Summary**

For some reason, my member function template that invokes a lambda function fails to compile with *error C2275 ... illegal use of this type as an expression*, but when the function is moved out to be a free function it compiles correctly.

**Details**

First I have a base class that keeps `function` instances in a `vector`. Only derived classes can add `function` instances to that `vector` by calling `add_external`. All `function` instances can be publicly invoked by calling `invoke_externals`. A derived class will add lambdas as `function` instances. Those lambdas will in turn call the base class function template `invoke_internal` with another "inner" lambda. The template parameter to `invoke_internal` is an exception type that will be explicitly caught when executing the "inner" lambda in `invoke_internal`:

```
using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
    void invoke_externals()
    {
        for (auto it = funcs_.begin(); it != funcs_.end(); ++it)
        {
            (*it)();
        }
    }

protected:
    void add_external(function<void(void)> func)
    {
        funcs_.push_back(func);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void invoke_internal(function<void(void)> func)
    {
        try
        {
            func();
        }
        catch (const T&){}
        catch (...){}
    }

    vector<function<void(void)>> funcs_;
};
```

Then I have two trivial free functions that throws `logic_error` and `runtime_error` exceptions. These functions are to be used in the "inner" lambda that is invoked in `invoke_internal`:

```
void throws_logic_error()
{
    throw logic_error("");
}

void throws_runtime_error()
{
    throw runtime_error("");
}
```

In the `derived` class constructor, two lambdas are added with `add_external`. Each of those lambdas call `invoke_internal` with "inner" lmbdas. The first call to `invoke_internal` will explicitly catch the `logic_error` that `throws_logic_error` will throw. The second call to `invoke_internal` will explicitly catch the `runtime_error` that `throws_runtime_error` will throw.

```
class derived : public base
{
public:
    derived()
    {
        add_external([this]()
        {
            invoke_internal<logic_error>([]()
            {
                throws_logic_error();
            });
        });

        add_external([this]()
        {
            invoke_internal<runtime_error>([]()
            {
                throws_runtime_error();
            }); 
        });
    }
};
```

And to tie all this together, `derived` is instantiated and `invoke_externals` is called to invoke the "external" lambdas added in the `derived` constructor. Those "external" lambdas will in turn invoke the "inner" lambdas and the thrown exceptions will be explicitly caught:

```
int wmain(int, wchar_t*[])
{
    derived().invoke_externals();

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem**

However, the above don't compile:

```
error C2275: 'std::logic_error' : illegal use of this type as an expression
error C2275: 'std::runtime_error' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

...is issued for the calls to `invoke_internal` in the `derived` constructor.

If I move `invoke_internal` out from `base` and make it a free function, then it compiles.

**Question**

Why do I get *error C2275 ... illegal use of this type as an expression* when the function template is a `base` member?

**Note:** Moving the offending function out of `base` isn't optimal since in my real life scenario the function actually do use its class' state in different ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @sehe's answer, I could test this myself on VS2010. The following code works:

```
derived()
{   //                       vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    add_external([this] () { this->template invoke_internal<logic_error>([]() { throws_logic_error(); }); });

    add_external([this] () { this->template invoke_internal<runtime_error>([]() { throws_runtime_error(); }); });
}   //                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Don't ask me why.Generally, the error that you get means, that the template, where the type was used, was not detected as such.

*Normally* this should only occur with dependent types / nested templates and can be solved with a `template` directly before the template in question (as shown), which tells the compiler that a template follows (duh). We need `this->` before that though, because else it would look like an explicit instantiation, which would be wrong on its own:

```
template Foo<int>; // explicitly instantiate the Foo class template for int
```

Now. strangly, this problem also occurs here and I can only agree with @sehe that this looks like a compiler limitation.

Answer (score 3):

That would look like a compiler limitation. It compiles fine on gcc 4.6 with --std=c++0x

In case anyone else wants to try, I did some work to actually copy/past this into a proper, compiling, TU:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:

        void invoke_externals()
        {
            for (auto it = funcs_.begin(); it != funcs_.end(); ++it)
            {
                (*it)();
            }
        }

    protected:

        void add_external(function<void(void)> func)
        {
            funcs_.push_back(func);
        }

        template <typename T>
            void invoke_internal(function<void(void)> func)
            {
                try
                {
                    func();
                }
                catch (const T&)
                {
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                }
            }

        vector<function<void(void)>> funcs_;
};

void throws_logic_error()   { throw logic_error("");   }
void throws_runtime_error() { throw runtime_error(""); }

class derived : public base
{
    public:

        derived()
        {
            add_external([this] () { invoke_internal<logic_error>([]() { throws_logic_error(); }); });

            auto g = [this] () { invoke_internal<runtime_error>([]() { throws_runtime_error(); }); };
            add_external(g);
        }
};

int main(int, char*[])
{
    derived().invoke_externals();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, a compiler limitation then. What say The Standard? Is it even a *bug*, and not just a *limitation*?

Comment: @Johann : MSVC10 implemented lambdas pre-N2927, so it's sort of a moot point as it's based on wording that is no longer in the FDIS. MSVC11 will have lambda support based on N3290.