# Accessing a class template parameter type inside a member function with a lambda fails

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11, traits

I have a class template with a member function that has a lambda which wants to use a class template parameter type. It fails to compile inside the lambda but succeeds, as anticipated, outside the lambda.

```
struct wcout_reporter
{
    static void report(const std::wstring& output)
    {
        std::wcout << output << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename reporter = wcout_reporter>
class agency
{
public:

    void report_all()
    {
        reporter::report(L"dummy"); // Compiles.

        std::for_each(reports_.begin(), reports_.end(), [this](const std::wstring& r)
        {
            reporter::report(r);    // Fails to compile.
        });
    }

private:

    std::vector<std::wstring> reports_;
};

int wmain(int /*argc*/, wchar_t* /*argv*/[])
{
    agency<>().report_all();

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation error:

```
error C2653: 'reporter' : is not a class or namespace name
```

Why can't I access the class template parameter type inside the member function lambda?

What do I need to do to gain access to the class template parameter type inside the member function lambda?

Comment: Compiles for me on GCC 4.6. What's your platform/compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use typedef:

```
template <typename reporter = wcout_reporter>
class agency
{
    typedef reporter _myreporter;
public:   
    void report_all()    
    {        
        reporter::report(L"dummy"); // Compiles.        

        std::for_each(reports_.begin(), reports_.end(), [this](const std::wstring& r)        
        {   
            // Take it
            agency<>::_myreporter::report(r);    
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Ah! I had already tried `typedef`ing, but missed the crucial `agency<>` - thanks!

Comment: But wont _myreporter always evaluate to `wcout_reporter`? since `agency<>` accepts the default parameter it is a shorthand for `agency<wcout_reporter>` and in that class `_myreporter` is typedefed as wcout_reporter. Or does mytempalte<> inside an instance of the template actually evaluate to itself?

Comment: That depends on compiler. VC10, for instance doesn't capture the namespace outside the lambda.

Answer (score 4):

This should compile OK as-is. It appears that your compiler has a bug in the name lookup rules in a lambda. You could try adding a `typedef` for `reporter` inside `report_all`.

Comment: Yes, VS 2010 has more of these in the C++0x context, for instance this one that I tripped over yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6432658/6345