# Compilation error when using class template parameter in lambda

Tags: c++, templates, delegates, lambda, c++11

I'm trying to recreate some of the behavior of C#'s delegate types in C++, and I'm running in to a particular error when compiling- here is the relevant code:

```cpp
struct Nil { };

// Represents a C# Func
template <typename returnType = void,
          typename T1 = Nil,
          typename T2 = Nil,
          typename T3 = Nil>
class Func
{
public:
    vector<function<returnType(T1, T2, T3)>> _funcs;

    void operator+=(returnType (*functionPointerToAdd)(T1))
    {
        auto myFunc = [&] ( returnType (*functionPointerToAdd)(T1) )
                     -> returnType (*)(T1, T2, T3)
                     { functionPointerToAdd(T1); };
        // add myFunc to the vector of functions...
    }
};
```

What I'm trying to do is wrap a function pointer in a closure whose signature matches the full template type of the class (effectively "throwing away" the values set to 'Nil'). The error I'm getting is:

```
error C2275: 'T1' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

I'm using MSVC10, and I tried typedef'ing the template variables as per [Accessing a class template parameter type inside a member function with a lambda fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442129/accessing-a-class-template-parameter-type-inside-a-member-function-with-a-lambda), to no avail. I realize there are a couple of issues with this particular implementation that I'll run into down the line but aside from that, I'm just curious as to why I can't use the class' template parameters in the lambda statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you still have the 0x syntax slightly messed up.

```
auto myFunc = [&] ( returnType (*functionPointerToAdd)(T1) ) -> returnType (*)(T1, T2, T3) { functionPointerToAdd(T1); };
```

This line is the problem. Let's pull it apart:

```
auto myFunc = [&]
```

This creates a local variable of undefined type that receives a lambda (which is fine) and starts a lambda, that takes the function pointer by reference. The pointer is going to go away, better make it a [=] for simplicity (you'll copy a full pointer more - no biggie).

```
( returnType (*functionPointerToAdd)(T1) )
```

This is the arguments to the lambda. This means that the lambda should be called (!) with a function pointer of the type returnType(*)(T1). That's not what you want - you want it to be called with T1, T2, T3.

```
-> returnType (*)(T1, T2, T3)
```

This defines the return type of the lambda - and only that. You're now saying that it has to return a function pointer, to a function returning a returnType and taking a T1, T2 and T3 as argument. The lambda type would then be

```
(returnType(*)(T1, T2, T3)) (*)(returnType(*)(T1))
```

, or a function that takes a function pointer as argument and that returns a function pointer. Yes, it's overly complex and unreadable.

```
{ functionPointerToAdd(T1); };
```

This finally is the contents of the lambda and the reason for your error. You're passing the type T1 as argument to the function pointer.

Suggestion for fixing it (as the syntax is horribly complex - I hope the above text will help you with why I changed what:

```
auto myFunc = [=] ( T1 arg, T2, T3 ) -> returnType { return functionPointerToAdd(arg); }
```

Feel free to ask why & how.

Comment: the `-> returnType` part is unnecessary, in this case, this makes the syntax easier on the eyes: https://ideone.com/uEH3N

Comment: Yeah, I included it in part for completeness (especially as he'd included it too) and in part because I forgot to notice it could be left out. I added the return last so I just kind of forgot.

Comment: Excellent explanation! As you could have probably guessed, this is my first foray into C++0x lambdas, and the syntax is a bit daunting (as opposed to something like C#'s syntax which I've been spoiled on anyway). Their use is much clearer to me now!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is exactly what the compiler says: your call `functionPointerToAdd(T1)` doesn't make sense. `T1` is a type, not a variable. Your lambda only takes a function pointer as an argument, but no actual object to call the function with!

Also, what's the lambda supposed to return? If its only purpose is to return `functionPointerToAdd(...)`, shouldn't its return type just be `returnType`?

Maybe something like this (but I don't understand your requirements fully):

```
typedef returnType (*myFP)(T1);

auto myFunc = [] (myFP f, const T1 & t) -> returnType { return f(t); };
```

I'm also getting rid of the "capture everything by reference" (`[&]`) because you don't seem to be using any non-local variables.

**Edit:** Oh wait, I see, you want to add `myFunc` to the vector. So you want to bind your given pointer to a lambda whose body consists of calling the function. OK, let's see:

```
void operator+=(myFP f)
{
  auto myFunc = [f] (T1 t, T2, T3) -> returnType { return f(t); };
  the_vector.push_back(myFunc);
}
```

But I doubt that you can do that, because lambdas that capture from the environment are not convertible to naked function pointers, I believe. We really need a proper function object for your situation, methinks.

Comment: It's supposed to close over a call to `functionPointerToAdd(...)`, which has a different signature then the functions contained in the vector. (Example: consider an instance of `Func` instantiated as `Func<void, int>`. It would actually be `Func<void, int, Nil, Nil>`. Using the single argument `operator+=` method, the desired behavior is for the function pointer passed in (with a return type of `void` and a single param of type `int`) to be wrapped in a closure whose return type is `void` and params are `int, Nil, Nil` so it can be added to the vector of functions.)

Comment: @Wells: Edited. I think you can't do it with a lambda, though!

Comment: Lambda's are full function objects. You can't store them in naked function pointers though. He's putting them in an std::function however, which is made to be used like this.

Comment: @dascandy: Are you sure that a lambda *with capture* can be converted to an `std::function`? This field relatively new to me, but I was under the impression that only non-capturing lambdas can do that.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: My face turned red when I read your first paragraph, I can't believe I missed that. I'm a little clearer on the syntax now though.

Comment: @Wells: No worries, but please do let us know if you make it work -- I'm very curious to see if lambdas can be used in that way! (Though I might just try it myself...)

Comment: Kerrek, can't say for sure but I'm fairly sure I have done that before. I do recall in the discussions about lambdas that an auto-variable is/may be more efficient at storing it than the std::function, but any will fit in an std::function of the appropriate type.

Comment: @dascandy: You're right, I just ran a small test in GCC4.6, and it appears that the lambda is indeed of type `std::function<returnType(T1,T2,T3)>`, despite the capture. Intriguing!

Comment: @Kerrek SB: It does indeed work- here's a copy of the test code I'm using (the Run method only runs the first method in the vector, but it's just for testing purposes) [link](http://pastebin.com/ujGBSSyC)

Comment: @Kerrek SB : What so intriguing? std::function is _designed_ to catch everything in C++ that is _callable_. std::function can be constructed from a function pointer, member function pointer, function-object etc. Since lambdas/closures are plain function-object, std::function can store them as well.

Comment: @Thomas: I confused `std::function` with function pointers -- I think function pointers can only be obtained from capture-less lambdas. Function objects are indeed universal. Cheers.